# T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING Zoho

Tags: php, curl, zoho, zohobooks

I am trying to insert a record zoho however i am getting the following error :
Uncaught ParseError: syntax error, unexpected ''https://www.zohoapis.com/crm/' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING) in wp-content/themes/tsahiasa/functions.php:486

I tried using both " (double quotes) and ' (single quotes) however i am still getting the error.
Below is my code snippet and the line with error :

```
**Line 486**  curl "https://www.zohoapis.com/crm/v2/Leads/insertRecords"
          -H "Authorization: Zoho-oauthtoken **************"
          -d "@newlead.json"   

-X POST{    
 "data": [
{
    "Lead_Owner": $zoho_lead_owner,
    "First_Name": $data['first_name'],
    "Last_Name": $data['last_name'],
    "Mobile": $data['phone_number'],
    "Email": data['email'],
    "Country_Of_Origin": $data['country'],
    "Client_Status": "Need Follow Up",
    "Client_Type": $zoho_lead_type,
    "Lead_Source": $zoho_lead_source,
    "Lead_Source_Description": $zoho_lead_source_desc,
    "Description": $zoho_ref_description,
    "Personal_Notes": "Kindly Add Notes"
}]
```

};

Comment: Whats this? Is this supposed to be PHP code?

Comment: This is a _command line_ cURL call, you can not plug that into a PHP script 1:1. You need to use PHP’s own cURL class, or have PHP execute the given cURL command on the shell.

Comment: Owwh yes, thank you so much. I get it now